# Is it possible to use the change method suffix for two-way binding with ngModel?

Tags: angular, properties, binding

I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to use the "hidden" mechanic of two-way bindings with the -Change suffix with ngModel. Example:

.html

```
<customElement [(ngModel)]="value">
</...>
```

.ts

```
@Component(...)
export class SomeComponent {
  value: Person;

  valueChange(value: Person) {
    console.log('success');
  } 
}
```

I know this mechanic works with custom two-way bindings and I'm sure the customElement (in my case either a vanilla `<input>` or `<ng-select>`) has ngModel support. But the method doesn't get called when the value changes.

**Edit**: I already tried renaming the `valueChange` method to `ngModelChange` in my TS code but it doesn't get automatically triggered unless I actually point the event in the HTML that way, which is more code than I thought is needed for two-way bindings.

Comment: You kinda answer your question at the end of the answer. Angular two way binding is no magic.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Angular two way binding has little magic in it. It is basically an input `[name]` and an output named `[name]Change`. The only magic that is provided to you is that these two values are connected to the bound property (`value`).

```
<component [(name)]="value">
```

is the equivalent of

```
<component [name]="value" (nameChange)="value = $event">
```

as described in [the docs](https://angular.io/guide/two-way-binding#how-two-way-binding-works).

So you can't get a method to be called automagically. On the other hand you can use a setter in your containing component. Using a private property allows you to write the value without calling the setter.

```
@Component({
  template: `<component [(name)]="value" />`
})
export class ContainingComponent {

    private _value: string

    get value() {
      return this._value
    }
    set value(val: string) {
      this._value = val;
      console.log("Received value from two-way binding!", val)
    }

    constructor() {
       // set the two-way-bound value without calling the setter
       this._value = new Date().toString()
    }

}
```

Comment: as say the docs, you only need define `@Ouput() name_of_variableChange` and  `@Input() name_of_variable`

Comment: yes, that would be the code inside of the <component>. I only provided code for Containing component.